# Error page in react not being linked to properly when specified

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Hi all I am attempting to create a simple error page in react: I did the following:
I started with creating the css page for the 404 error page called 404page.css with the path public/css/404page.css, so the css folder is inside the public folder and the file is inside the css folder:

```
h1{
    font-size:80px;
    font-weight:800;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
  }
  h2{
    font-size:25px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'Roboto',sans-serif;
    margin-top:-40px;
  }
  p{
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'Roboto',sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
  }
  .container
  {
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top: 15%;
  }
```

I then created the js file called 404errorpage.js with the path pages/404errorpage.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import '/../404page.css'


const NoMatch=()=>{

  return(
    <div class='container'>
    <h1 >404</h1>
    <h2 >Page Not Found</h2>
    <p >The page that you are looking for doesn't exist or another error occurred.</p>

    </div>
  )
}
export default NoMatch;
```

Now I am attempting to test the page out on a file called sr.js with the path components/background/sr.js so I did the following within the file:

```
 <p> testing out the 404page click here <Link href= "pages/404errorpage">this</Link> </p>
```

when I run it locally however and click on the link I am directed to the standard error page, not the one that I created.
Here is a picture of the error page:

[image]

I am following an example that I saw online but for some reason mine is not working? any ideas on what I am doing wrong? or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Are you using react-router? Can you show your Router / Switch / Route setup?

Comment: Your import should be `./css/404page.css` or `./css/404page.module.css`. Maybe it's giving the other error page because your error page has an error in it.

Comment: @Webber I updated the import and still the same problem.

Comment: What is your error page saying?

Comment: @ChrisG I am not using react router. I am a bit new to react and do not know how to use that setup. How would it be done with react router?

Comment: @Webber it is simply saying 404 this page could not be found. I posted the picture of it in my edit.

Comment: If you aren't using react-router, where are you getting the `<Link>` component from? Also, in general, React apps are SPAs (single page applications). They do not use standard navigation, because that would unload the entire React app and load a new page.

Comment: I have specified it through the " import Link from "next/link";" declaration in the sr.js file. It works fine as I have used It  in other files @ChrisG

Comment: Ohhh..k. That mean's you're using next.js, which is *very* pertinent information. I've never used it myself, but from a quick look [here](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2020/12/08/making-a-custom-404-page-in-next.js/) apparently all you need to do is call the file `404.js` and put it in your pages folder. Then you link to some arbitrary but non-existent page, like `href="/idontexist"` (also, if you're following a tutorial, it's a good idea to link to it in your question)

Comment: @ChrisG yeah that was really helpful, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome :) Regarding importing files: their path is always relative to the current file's path. The simplest way is to put the css file in the same folder as the js.file, then use `import './404style.js';` or similar. The public folder is for static files, that aren't connected to a specific component. A stylesheet in public for instance would usually be linked by `<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/style.css">` inside your main index.html. Still, this is how React does it, so next.js might be different. But `import` usually works that way regardless of the framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Nextjs, you can follow their official [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page#404-page) on how to make error pages.

It involves creating a file called `404.js` inside the `pages` folder specifically.

```js
// pages/404.js
export default function Custom404() {
  return <h1>404 - Page Not Found</h1>
}
```

To use css, you can use either the CSS that is loaded in _app.js or css modules.

I would recommend to create a component that is mounted inside the error page.

for example:

```js
// components/my-error-page.js
import styles from './my-error-page.module.css'

const MyErrorPage = () => {
  return <div className={styles.container}>Page was not found</div>
}

export default MyErrorPage
```

Which you then load into the error page:

```
// pages/404.js
import MyErrorPage from '../components/my-error-page'

export default function Custom404() {
  return <MyErrorPage />
}
```

Comment: this worked like a charm and the 404 is finally changing, however when I attempt to customize by mounting inside the my-error-page.js. I am getting an error saying that the ./my-error-page.module.css is not found or cannot be resolved inside the my-error-page.js even after I created the file my-error-page.module.css inside the path public/css/my-error-page.css, is there a reason im getting an error for the css again?

Comment: you don't put css in the public folder anymore nowadays (with most frameworks), it all gets compiled with the components (though for global global css you have to import it in `_app.js`). So if your component is named `MyComponent`, then it should be in file `my-component.js` and the css should be in `my-component.module.css` (in the same folder). I refer to these two methods in the third line of the answer. Hope that helps.